# How can control the color depth for RealVNC on Macintosh?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, realvnc, color-depth

I'm running RealVNC enterprise edition 5 on Macintosh but what is normally a grey background of my editor window is now a pink or purple color.  It almost looks as if the color depth is limited to 256 colors but I see no preference for the color depth.

How can I get the real grey color of my window to display on my Macintosh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was indeed color depth, however, it was not a depth setting but a compression setting.  To resolve, go to the Preferences... dialog of RealVNC and in the Display section uncheck the `Adapt to network speed (recommended)` check box and move the slider to the right a few notches until you choose one with a tool tip that includes the words `All available colors`.  With this done, you get full color depth and no longer get weird colors.